# Future object in getter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am calling a future object in my getter for my Locale variable.

How do I let the return value wait for it?

```
class ChangeLocale with ChangeNotifier {

  Locale _locale;

  Locale get locale {
    getLanguage().then((Locale prefLocale) {
      _locale = prefLocale;
    });
    return _locale;
  }

  set locale(Locale newValue) {
    print(newValue);
    _locale = newValue;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the value before `then`'s callback is executed, so if the initial value of `_locale` is `null`, the getter will return `null`.

As soon as `getLanguage()`'s `Future` is resolved, `_locale` value is going to be updated, but at that point it will be too late.

Instead, you must do:

```dart
Locale _locale;

Locale get locale async {
  return _locale = await getLanguage();
}
```

But I'd rather creating a method that makes it clear you are doing an asynchronous operation:

```
Future<Locale> fetchLocale() async {
  _locale = await getLanguage();
  return _locale;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what do I do about the getter then? Basically I wanted to fetch the locale I saved with shared preferences, when I start the App in the MaterialApp Widget with `locale: Provider.of<ChangeLocale>(context).locale`

Comment: If you saved it your shared preferences, why are you using provider? Why don't you get the locale from shared preferences directly?

Comment: So that the app directly applies changes, when I switch between languages on the settings page. I have a working solution now - entirely different approach. But thanks again :)